# Can I deploy SSR nuxt.js application on GitHub/GitLab pages?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, github-pages, server-side-rendering

Is it possible to deploy a server-side rendering application with nuxt.js (universal ssr mode) and firebase backend on GitHub/Gitlab Page? Gitlab gives its example on [nuxt](https://gitlab.com/pages/nuxt), and I wonder if the dynamic fetching on server side still works.

Comment: no its not possible. gh-pages is static, there is no nodejs running to render. You will also find there is no fallback for nested routes so going to /page/1 etc will work from / but on reload will not work and you'll get a 404 error. History mode off works fine

Comment: @LawrenceCherone, Using `hashrouter` instead of `browserrouter` is the way to go for routing to work in gh-pages.

Answer (score 0):

These pages are static, so no server side rendering. You could check the nuxt pre-rendering options: https://nuxtjs.org/blog/going-full-static/, not sure what exactly are the limitations here though.

Comment: Fresh article: https://nuxtjs.org/blog/nuxt-static-improvements